# Generating short unique reference id with PHP uniqid function

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, uniqueidentifier

My objective is to create a unique id attach it to a record and store it in the DB. The id should be alpha - numeric and short. I don not want to use the auto increment way of generating ids as this ID is going to be attached to end of a url so I don't want it to be guessable.  After some research I have decided to use uniqid() as i understood that its generated based on time.

My worry is will it be unique across the system and is there a chance for 
the id to become repeated if i am going scale my system using multiple servers and clustering??

i don't want to do a duplicate check before inserting the value into the DB as this can affect the performance over time as records increase.

I am using Larvel framework. Can anyone suggest any other solution to tackle this problem. I am new to laravel.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you considered using mysql's built-in uuid() function instead?

Comment: @Shadow mysql uuid() function gives a result thats around 36 characters long and UUID_SHORT() function is almost 17 characters. I want something small

Comment: You have conflicting requirements. You want something short, nevertheless globally unique.

Comment: you can prefix with the server name/symbol, so all uniqeid from server a will start with a etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the suggestions. I have decided to use uniqid() with prefix as user_id. As uniqid() is system time dependent and can cause a conflict when 2 simultaneous requests hit the server, the user_id prefix will make sure that even if simultaneous request comes it will generate different ids since the user_id associated with each request will be different.